# JPA Criteria API Specification for Many to One

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, criteriaquery

I have two tables Student and Address. One student can have multiple address.
Entities looks like this

```
@Entity @Table(name = "STUDENT") 
public class Student {
  @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID") Integer studentId;
  @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME") String fName;
  @Column(name = "LAST_NAME") String LName;
}

@Entity @Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
  @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID") Integer addressId;
  @Column(name = "STREET_NAME") String street_name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
  private Student student;
}
```

I need to use JPA Criteria to fetch all addresses based on a student fName and LName. It can be with INNER JOIN or even it can be sub-query for Address table.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Address> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Address.class);

Root<Address> fromAddress = criteriaQuery.from(Address.class);
//Can be a JOIN or Sub-Query.
em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Requirement is to load only now Address table data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Address> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Address.class);

    Root<Address> fromAddress = criteriaQuery.from(Address.class);
    //join
    Join<Address, Student> studentJoin = fromAddress.join("student");
    //where
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(
            builder.equal(studentJoin.get("fName"), fName),
            builder.equal(studentJoin.get("lName"), lName)
    ));
    //projection
    criteriaQuery.select(fromAddress);
    return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```